# Firefox binary extension: nsISupports to JS::Value

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, xpcom

I am trying to implement nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer::Init().

I have an existing object (based on Google Gears) that I am trying to extend to support JAVASCRIPT_GLOBAL_PROPERTY_CATEGORY (since JAVASCRIPT_DOM_CLASS does not seem to work in FF17 anymore).

My implementation of nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer::Init() is being called, but how do I convert my C++ object (it implements nsISupports and exposes the appropriate IDL) to JS:Value to make my object available in Java Script?

If I return NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED or do not implement the nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer interface, FF (rightfully) complains that the no method or property is exposed by the object.

Comment: Maybe through nsXPConnect::WrapNativeToJSVal?

Comment: But where would nsXPConnect come from?

Comment: `nsXPConnect* xpc = nsXPConnect::GetXPConnect();`

Comment: But nsXPConnect.cpp lives in js\xpconnect\src\ (which is the FF source tree), it is not in the SDK (which I am linking against).

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko did you succeed on that? I'm trying to implement C++ extension for FF which should expose it's interface to JS and worrying that it's not feasible at all...

Comment: No, I pretty much gave up..

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert your object to JS:Value. If you implement XPCOM interfaces like nsISupports, they will be available in JavaScript. It's not clear from your description exactly what your object does, but you probably have to write a custom interface in IDL and implement it in your object. You can then manipulate it in JS through this interface. You should probably implement [`nsISecurityCheckedComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsISecurityCheckedComponent) and [`nsIClassInfo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/nsIClassInfo) as well.

Comment: Yes, my object already implements nsISupports. JAVASCRIPT_GLOBAL_CONSTRUCTOR_CATEGORY does not work in FF 17 anymore, so I am trying implement JAVASCRIPT_GLOBAL_PROPERTY_CATEGORY. But if I do that, FF does not see any properties or methods on my object because it requires the nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer interface to be implemented. And to implement nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer::Init, I need to cnvert my object to JS::Value.

Comment: Have you tried implementing `nsISecurityCheckedComponent`? It's more likely that this is the reason JS doesn't see your component's properties. As far as I know you don't need to implement `nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer` unless you want your component to have access to the window (though they may have changed this since I like implemented a JS global property).

Comment: nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer did not help :-( FF does not even query my object for that interface.

Comment: As for the nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer, I can see FF (from nsWindowSH::GlobalResolve() in nsDOMClassInfo.cpp) creating an instance of my global property and defaulting its value to JSVAL_VOID. It then proceeds to query my object for nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer and calls nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer::Init(), which is the method that I am having problems with...

Comment: You may be right. It looks like the changed the behavior in [bug 773803](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=773803), so perhaps now `nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer` is required. You can instantiate XPConnect using XPCOM (basically `nsCOMPtr<nsIXPConnect> xpc(do_GetService(nsIXPConnect::GetCID()));`) but I'm not sure how you'd get the right `JSContext` from the window to create a `JSVal`. Any particular reason you can't simply implement your global property in JavaScript?

Comment: In other words, use the XPCOM interfaces you added to your component to access the required functionality from your JS component, which will implement `nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer`. It might be possible to create a `JSVal` in an extension from C++, but I'd have to do more research to figure out how.